# Начиная с какой модификации не возникает проблем в работе Android Studio на Макбуке?

Tags: android, macbook, air

Подскажите, кто работает в Android Studio на Макбуке, начиная с какой модификации не возникает проблем в работе среды, много читал, что на старых моделях на процессорах core 2 duo возникают многочисленные проблемы, в том числе с работой эмулятора. Есть необходимость в написание одного несложного проекта под Android и IOS, хочу взять поддержанный макбук для выполнения задачи, чтоб на одном устройстве все делать под обе платформы, но не хочу брать новый. Подойдет ли macbook air на i5 годов  2012-2013 или можно и ранние модификации?

Answer (score 0):

Самое главное смотрите на память, так как это наиболее критичное, минимум от 4G для работы с IDE, хотя конечно без IDE только Gradle+build tools может собирать и с 2Г. Идеально 8Г и более для Studio 3+ и SDK 25+

Comment: А как на счет версии процессора? Если я возьму макбук годов 2008-2010 на Core 2 Duo 2.4GHz,  добавлю туда памяти до 8 и SSD, не будет проблем с работой Android Studio в плане совместимости с такой старой моделью?

Comment: На Core2Duo может не встать свежая MacOSX которая нужна для свежего Xcode.  ЧТо то вроде 10.7 встанет, а дальше с приседаниями. Лучше смотреть в сторону hackintosh/macosx86

Answer (score 0):

MBP 13' Late 2011, Core i5, 4GB, macOS 10.12

И IDE и эмулятор работают идеально, если кроме них открыт только Safari.

Брал в 2015 за 25к, сейчас находил предложения за ~13к

Answer (score 0):

MBP 17'' Late 2011, Core i7 4*2.4, 16GB, macOS 10.14.6.

У меня сам Android Studio отдельно от эмулятора работает нормально, но в паре с родным эмулятором грузит процессор на 100%. В паре с эмулятором Genymotion грузит процессор на 100% уже не сам Android Studio, а системный процесс Windowserver. Так что в любом случае эмулятором не получается пользоваться. В паре с физическим устройством вроде нормально работает.

Есть подозрение что если понизить версию macOS - то может и нормально заработает, но не факт, и пока не пробовал. Но даже если заработает - то на более старую macOS не встанет новый Xcode.